# How do I get a ggplot to start the x axis from specific month

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, lubridate, purrr

I want to plot a chart of goals scored in soccer games by month for a season that starts in November but rolls over into the next year. So I want to have the x axis
go Nov,Dec,Jan etc.

This is where I have got to with some toy data

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2017-11-01","2017-11-15",
                              "2017-12-01","2017-12-15",
                              "2018-01-01","2018-01-15")),
             goals = c(3,2,0,1,3,5))

df %>% 
  mutate(month=month(date,label = TRUE)) %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  summarize(totGoals=sum(goals)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(month,totGoals)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Ideally, I'd like to use the purrr package to overcome the problem but am having trouble getting to grips with fct_reorder and fct_relevel. 'month' is an ordered factor

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert the `month` column to factor and set the level begins with `Nov`. `month.abb` is a built-in R object with month abbreviations.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(month=month(date,label = TRUE)) %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  summarize(totGoals=sum(goals)) %>% 
  mutate(month = factor(month, levels = c(month.abb[11:12], month.abb[1:10]))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(month,totGoals)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Comment: @Tung It was close! Glad we have same thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Plot YYYY-MM instead of just MM, that way it'll order it by the year.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(date = c("2017-11","2017-11",
                          "2017-12","2017-12",
                          "2018-01","2018-01"),
                 goals = c(3,2,0,1,3,5))

df = df %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarize(totGoals=sum(goals))

plot = ggplot(df, aes(date,totGoals)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

print(plot)
```

[image]

Comment: That's an interesting option but I want to show month labels and extend chart ir real life version to  a facet for several seasons